# Wordpress Query + ACF Meta Query

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am looking for a code that can contain all queries in one.

The part of the code is :

```
            <?php $query = new WP_Query(array (  'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => '6', 'order' => 'DESC', 'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type-article',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'interview', 'tribune' )
        ) ) ));

            while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                $query->the_post();  ?>


                <?php if($post->post_type == "post"){ $version_FR = get_field('versionFRexiste'); $langue = get_field('langue'); }; ?>
                <?php if($langue == "FR" || ($langue == "EN"  && $version_FR == "Non")) :  ?>

                [some code]

                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

inside the WHILE, you find two lines with IF

I would like to include these condition in the query at the TOP where WP_Query.

This code is working but my problem is that I would like to have the same number of results to display (6 here)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look here on  the [ACF Docs](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/).

The answer is to write a meta query within the WP-Query, such as:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
'numberposts'   => -1,
'post_type'     => 'post',
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'      => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => 'color',
        'value'     => array('red', 'orange'),
        'compare'   => 'IN',
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'featured',
        'value'     => '1',
        'compare'   => '=',
    ),
),
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. It was not so easy... but the metaquery won

```
            <?php $query = new WP_Query(array (  'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'order' => 'DESC', 
                        'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'OR',
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'langue',
                                    'value' => 'FR'
                                ),
                                array(
                                       'relation' => 'AND',
                                        array(
                                            'key' => 'langue',
                                            'value' => 'EN'
                                            ),
                                        array(
                                            'key' => 'versionFRexiste',
                                            'value' => 'Non'
                                            )
                                    )
                            ),

        'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type-article',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'interview', 'tribune' )
        ) ) ));
```

Hope this will help those who need an answer